# jQuery val() not getting live result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

OK so I'm doing a "quick search" kind of thing. I have jQuery GET request everytime a field on a form changes but it's not working. I have provided an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Don't worry about the AJAX call because the thing that's not working is the request. For example, if I tick `19`, the GET request will STILL be `Pick one`.

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled 3</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var test = $(".age1").val();
            alert(test);
            var dataString = "test=" + test;
            $("#formtest").live("change", function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "quick_search.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#display").after(html);
                    }
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="quick_search.php" id="formtest" method="GET"> 
        live GET
        <select class="age1" name='age1'>
            <option value='Pick One'>- Pick One -</option>
            <option value='16'>16</option>
            <option value='17'>17</option>
            <option value='18'>18</option>
            <option value='19'>19</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the value of `dataString` every time the value changes. Currently you are only changing it on page load, therefore it never changes after.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. It's the little things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to move `var test = $(".age1").val();` inside your change-function

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#formtest").live("change", function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "quick_search.php",
       data: "test=" + $(".age1").val(),
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
          $("#display").after(html);
       }
    });
  });
});
```